# Java automatic filling of ArrayList, searching for better options

Tags: java

I'm using this code here to automatically fill a string array list with the directory path of obj files for later use in animations, but there's a small problem with this:

```
private List<String> bunny_WalkCycle = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private int bunny_getWalkFrame = 0;

private void prepare_Bunny_WalkCycle() {

    String bunny_walkFrame = "/bunnyAnimation/bunnyFrame0.obj";

    while(bunny_WalkCycle.size() != 30) { // 30 obj files to loop through

        if(bunny_getWalkFrame != 0) {
            bunny_walkFrame = 
                "/bunnyAnimation/bunnyWalkAnim/bunnyWalkFrame_"+bunny_getWalkFrame+".obj";          
        }

        bunny_WalkCycle.add(bunny_getWalkFrame);

        bunny_getWalkFrame++;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the naming convention in blender for animations has zeros before the actual numbers, so something like this:

```
bunnyWalkFrame_000001.obj
bunnyWalkFrame_000002.obj
bunnyWalkFrame_000003.obj
...
bunnyWalkFrame_000030.obj
```

With my prepare_Bunny_WalkCycle method I cannot account for the zeros so I would change the names and get rid of the zeros.. This may be okay for not so many frames but once I hit 100 frames it would get painfull.. So there's my question:

What would be an intelligent way to account for the zeros in the code instead of having to rename every file manually and remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem with ["String.format"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

```
String blenderNumber = String.format("%06d", bunny_getWalkFrame);
```

Explanation:

- 0 -> to put leading zeros
- 6 -> "width" of them / amount of them

And so this would be your new bunny_walkFrame:

```
 bunny_walkFrame = "/bunnyAnimation/bunnyWalkAnim/bunnyWalkFrame_" + blenderNumber + ".obj";
```

Comment: but there are not always 5 zeros, for example: bunnyWalkFrame_000030.obj or does this not matter?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't matter. The code above + 30 as "bunny_getWalkFrame" will give "000030" as result. (// EDIT: Noticed to change from 5 to 6 to get your wanted result)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.format()` to pad your numbers with zeros:

```
String.format("%05d", yournumber);
```

Comment: but there are not always 5 zeros, for example: bunnyWalkFrame_000030.obj or does this not matter?

Comment: 5 is not the number of zeros, it's the total digit's length of the string. In your example you'd actually need 6, will give you `000001` and `000030`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options. First, you can use a string formatter to create your filenames with leading zeros:

```
bunny_WalkCycle.add("/bunnyAnimation/bunnyFrame0.obj");
for (int frame = 1; frame <= 30; frame++) {
    bunny_WalkCycle.add(
            String.format("/bunnyAnimation/bunnyWalkAnim/bunnyWalkFrame_%06s.obj", frame));
}
```

The second option is, if you already have all the required files in the directory, you can get them all in one go:

```
bunny_WalkCycle.add("/bunnyAnimation/bunnyFrame0.obj");
bunny_WalkCycle.addAll(Arrays.asList(new File("/bunnyAnimation/bunnyWalkAnim").list()));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could do that:
Appending the right number of leading zeroes, or using a String formatter.

1. bunny_walkFrame = "/bunnyAnimation/bunnyWalkAnim/bunnyWalkFrame_" + String.format("%05d", bunny_getWalkFrame) + ".obj";

OR

2. bunny_walkFrame = "/bunnyAnimation/bunnyWalkAnim/bunnyWalkFrame_" + getLeadingZeroes(bunny_getWalkFrame) + String.valueOf(bunny_getWalkFrame) + ".obj";

where

```
private String getLeadingZeroes(int walk) {
    String zeroes = "";
    int countDigits = 0;
    while (walk > 0) {
        countDigits++;
        walk /= 10;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= (nZeroes - countDigits); i++) {
        zeroes += "0";
    }
    return zeroes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Just specify how many digits you want. Set it to one. If it has to it will push over (so it won't cut digits off)